# Append YouTube embedded video title

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youtube

I'm trying to loop over every YouTube video in a page (using the `iframe` embed method) and append to each the title of the video, using jQuery. My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/qzNSsDD_LzE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery looks like this:

```
var video = $('.video-container');
video.each(function() {
  var youTuberegex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})/g,
      videoID = youTuberegex.exec($(this).find('iframe').attr('src'))[1];

  $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+videoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc', function(data){
    var videoTitle = data.data.title;
    video.after('<figcaption>'+videoTitle+'</figcaption>');
  });         
});
```

So, I am (trying to) take each video and use a regex to extract the ID. I then use the video feed to retrieve the title, and append it to the `video-container`.

This is in [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/AwqWF/). As you can see, the problem is that the title of each video is appended every time. Where am I going wrong, and is this an efficient way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *video* variable refers to the entire set of objects that match the selector ".video-container" so when you are doing

```
video.after('<figcaption>'+videoTitle+'</figcaption>');
```

It is doing that on each one.

What you need to do is something like:

```
video.each(function() {
  var videoBox = $(this)
  var youTuberegex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com(?:\/embed\/|\/v\/|\/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})/g,
      videoID = youTuberegex.exec($(this).find('iframe').attr('src'))[1];

  $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+videoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc', function(data){
    var videoTitle = data.data.title;
    videoBox.after('<figcaption>'+videoTitle+'</figcaption>');
  });         
});
```

The videoBox variable points to the specifc div for that video.