# Youtube Api response fo video title string "https://youtube.com/devicesupport"

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

For all videos youtube Api response :

```
    $.getJSON( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+videoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',
 function(data){
    var videoTitle = data.data.title; 
//"https://youtube.com/devicesupport"
            });
```

Youtube changed API ?

[Append YouTube embedded video title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342658/append-youtube-embedded-video-title)

[Getting a Youtube video title using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019762/getting-a-youtube-video-title-using-angularjs)

jssfiddle  http://plnkr.co/edit/ElWctwROCR9wdJB4KEIB?p=preview

**UPD  YOUTUBE API v3:**

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?alt=json',function(data,status,xhr){
    console.log(data.entry.title.$t);
});
```

but data.entry.title.$t  = "https://youtube.com/devicesupport"

Comment: I think you forgot the question part to your question.  What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API v3 search for videos, retrieve title and url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746449/youtube-api-v3-search-for-videos-retrieve-title-and-url)

Answer (score 1):

Your request string is using `v=2` and version 2 is deprecated.

> Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.

See their [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#videos).

It looks like you want your URL to be, [source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=gzDS-Kfd5XQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

See also: [Youtube API v3 search for videos, retrieve title and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746449/youtube-api-v3-search-for-videos-retrieve-title-and-url)

Comment: If that's from you simply changing the 2 to a 3, I'm not surprised. It looks like their api has changed quite a bit. You should spend some time looking through their documentation.

Comment: I changed for v3 but  problem is stayed

Comment: No, you didn't. According to their documentation, your update is still wrong. If you disagree, show me where the API call you are using is documented.